# Is there anyway to log after save with Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring-data-rest

I'm trying to logging some information after save entity with Spring Data Repository, is there anyway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Annotated repo event handlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler).

Just add the **@RepositoryEventHandler** annotation to your handler class, than in this class implement the handler method with **@HandleAfterCreate** and **@HandleAfterSave** annotations.

```java
    @RepositoryEventHandler 
    public class EventHandler {

      @HandleAfterCreate
      @HandleAfterSave
      public void handleAfterCreateOrSave(Entity e) {
        // LOG...
      }
    }
```

Comment: he is talking about Spring data, not spring data rest... This isen't triggered in Spring data.

Comment: @Maurice see the tag of his question... ;)

Comment: Do you guys know any other tool to do the same thing when we are using only spring-data? (not spring-data-rest)

Comment: @jhonata.sobrinho you mean something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242457/5380322)?..

Comment: That's a different think but an interesting approach... I would like something to be executed after the transaction is commited without have to explicitly change anything else in the service code.

Comment: @jhonata.sobrinho Instead of `EventListener` you can use [@TransactionalEventListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html). By default it triggers after the transaction has been committed (see the [phase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html#phase--) parameter). More info you can find [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events)

Comment: @jhonata.sobrinho and of cause you can simply [publish and handle](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#publishing-events) your own custom events in your service layer. Even [asynchronously](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events-async)...

Comment: i'm using the @TransactionalEventListener already, but I need to publish  the event inside the transaction. I want to remove this publishing phase of my code and kind of attach an event to the save method.