# Does Spring Data REST event hanlders use separate database transactions?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

Spring Data REST has the following Event handlers which are fired on HTTP requests like POST, PUT etc.

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Author.class) 
public class AuthorEventHandler {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Class AuthorEventHandler");

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleAuthorBeforeCreate(Author author){
        logger.info("Inside Author Before Create....");

    }

    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleAuthorAfterCreate(Author author){
        logger.info("Inside Author After Create ....");

    }

}
```

My question is if I access another database entity, eg.Book, within @HandleBeforeCreate and modify it, would it occur in a separate transaction or will it occur in the same transaction as the creation of the Author entity?

I already check the Spring Data REST docs but it is not mentioned there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, those handlers are performed beyond the main transaction. Literally 'before' and 'after' it. About 'separate' transaction - if you mark your event handler as `@Transactional` it will be executed in its individual transaction.

---

### Publishing domain events from the aggregate root

If you need to perform some extra actions within the main transaction you can use [publishing events from the aggregate root](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.domain-events).  In this case, you should extend your entity from [AbstractAggregateRoot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractAggregateRoot.html) and add to it some methods that register appropriate events, for example:

```
@Entity
public class Model extends AbstractAggregateRoot {

   // entity stuff...

   public Model initExtraAction(SomeData payload) {
        registerEvent(new ExtraActionEvent(this, payload));
        return this;
   }
}
```

where [registerEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/AbstractAggregateRoot.html#registerEvent-T-) is the `AbstractAggregateRoot` method, and `ExtraActionEvent` is your custom event, like the folowing:

```
@Value
public class ExtraActionEvent {
    private Model model;
    private SomeData payload;
}
```

Then you can implement an ordinary event handler

```
@Service
public class EventHandler {

    @EventListener
    @Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY) // optional 
    public void handleExtraActionEvent (ExtraActionEvent e) {
        Model model = e.getModel();
        SomeData payload = e.getPayload();

        // Extra actions...
    }
}
```

that will be called in the **same** transaction as the main one (which saves your entity) if you call `initExtendAction` method **before** invoking the `save` method of your repo (to make sure that this will be done in the same transaction you can use an **optional** `@Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)` annotation):

```
modelRepo.save(model.initExtraAction(payload));
```

In the **Spring Data REST** project we can call `initExtraAction` method in the 'RepositoryEventHandler' before the entity will be created or updated:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Model.class) 
public class ModelEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeCreateOrSave(Model model){
        // Some manipulations...
        model.initExtraAction(...);
    }
}
```

You can find a full example of using `AbstractAggregateRoot` in the Oliver Gierke [Spring RestBucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/85ce832553a1e15cde6b6035d464f3e3b9601926/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/order/Order.java#L99) demo project.

Additional info: [DDD Aggregates and @DomainEvents](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-ddd)

Comment: Hi @Cepr0, I am having a similar issue here, I am updating 2 entities from same transaction (ABC and PQR). ABC transaction will be updated from the event and PQR will be updated within HandleAfterSave annotated method. I need to roll back 1st transaction (ABC updating) if 2nd transaction fails (PQR updating). Transactional doesn't work here and I am thinking it is because the 1st transaction is done through a RepositoryEventHandler event and it executed using a separate thread. And HandleAfterSave method cannot rollback that due to that. any suggestions. OK to use compensating transaction